# Disabling tor proxy in tor browser bundle 6.5a1-hardened?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I enjoy using Firefox as my regular browser but as I'm running linux and it's not so easy to fully sandbox applications, I would prefer to run a modified TBB-hardened version as my desktop browser. I do not need to use the tor proxy network. I understand that this defeats anonymity and privacy but I would like to have some additional protection with Firefox and TBB-hardened provides that with selfrando. Do any of you very knowledgeable users know how to do this? I am not opposed to recompiling TBB-hardened.